# Ribbon Generator not generating .ribbon file

Tags: .net, winforms, ribbon

I am trying to setup my .net WinForms app to use the windows ribbon api using the library from http://windowsribbon.codeplex.com/

I followed the quick start guide http://bernhardelbl.wordpress.com/2010/11/17/quickstart-tutorial-windows-ribbon-for-winforms/ as well as trying the sample code.

However the .ribbon file doesn't get generated, just the .rc and .res files.

When I run the app I get the error:
Ribbon resource 'RibbonMarkup.ribbon' not found in assembly 'C:\Code\BookingSystem\FrontEnd\bin\Debug\FrontEnd.exe'.

I followed the steps in the quick start guide exactly so I don't know where the problem is and since the other files are generated I don't think it is to do with paths. I got the latest version of the Windows 7 SDK too.

Anyone know what I might be missing? Is there updates I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed this error. You have to install `Windows 7 SDK`. Then check if folder "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\" exists(in my case it was called v7.0). So i just renamed it on "v7.1". Now just rightclick on Ribbon.xml file in VS and click "Run custom tool". Ribbon.ribbon file now must appear.